# Is it possible to mkae std::ifstream.good() return false manually?

Tags: io, c++17, visual-studio-2022, interpreter, ifstream

I am making an interpreter that heavily uses the `>>` operator of the `std::ifstream` object. Is it possible to do something along the lines of the code specified bellow:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifstream = std::ifstream();
    ifstream.open("textfile.txt");
    char c = '\0';
    
    ifstream >> c
    if (c != '{') {
        // do something to ifstream object that makes ifstream.good() return false
        // Even when it read a character successfully
        // Reason: c != '{'
    }
    ifstream.close();
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because I am overriding the `>>` operator for a lot of objects and want to be notified when the interpreter encountered something that was not supposed to encounter, like a syntax error in the file format.

For reference, this is how overloading the operator looks like:

```
std::ifstream& operator >> (std::ifstream& ifstream, SomeObject& someObject) {
    // Interpret data
    // Make ifsteeam.good() return false if syntax error found
}
```

As you can see, I cannot return a `bool` value. If I cannot make `ifstream.good()` return `false` manually, is there an alternative and viable solution? I need this to make other pieces of my code to know that no more reading should be done when using that `ifstream` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the member function [`setstate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate):

```cpp
std::ifstream& operator >> (std::ifstream& ifstream, SomeObject& someObject) {
    // process stuff
    if (something_failed) {
        ifstream.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    return ifstream;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out! This works 100% and is what I was looking for. Reading though the docs, I expected to find it named as ```flag``` instead of ```state```

Comment: @ChristopherBarriosAgosto Great! You're welcome! I was about to add [an example](https://godbolt.org/z/77T7na7zM) but I guess that's not needed :-)